# Laravel sushi model: one-way relationship to regular model not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sushi

I have a [sushi](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi) model (Phone) that has a relationship with a regular model (User).

Sushi supports [relationships with regular models](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi#relationships).

It is a one way relationship: a phone is linked to a user, but the user model does not know anything about phones (i.e. does does not have a user_id column, and does not have a phone hasOne method).

Expected result:

- `App\Models\Sushi\Phone::find(1)->user` // User 1
- (not needed: `App\Models\Sushi\User::find(1)->phone`)

I get an error message when User is a regular model (using default migration).
It works fine when the User model is a sushi model.

Error message:

```
[41m Illuminate\Database\QueryException [49m SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users (Connection: App\Models\Sushi\Phone, SQL: select * from "users" where "users"."id" = 1 limit 1).
```

Suggestions?

`Phone` model (sushi)

```
namespace App\Models\Sushi;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Phone extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;

    protected $rows = [
        ['id' => 1, 'number' => '123', 'user_id' => 1],
        ['id' => 2, 'number' => '456', 'user_id' => null],
        ['id' => 3, 'number' => '789', 'user_id' => 2],
    ];

    // App\Models\Sushi\Phone::find(1)->user
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        // works when referring to another Sushi model
        // return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Sushi\User::class);

        // fails when referring to regular Model: no such table users
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class);
    }

}
```

`User` model (sushi)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Sushi;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class User extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;

    // need one way relationship: App\Models\Sushi\Phone::find(1)->user
    // don't need reverse relationship: App\Models\Sushi\User::find(1)->phone
    // so: no phone_id column in model, and no phone relationship method

    protected $rows = [
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'User 1'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'User 2'],
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'User 3'],
    ];

}
```

Comment: I would suggest to not use `Sushi`, if you are having this issue debuging it and fixing it, I would stick to normal usage (database) so it works as expected. May I ask why do you need to use `Sushi`? I have never saw it and now I am curious why you would need to use it (I have some edge cases in mind, but they are that, edge cases). Can you please share the error as I have no idea why it is not working when mixing `Sushi` with normal usecase (database)

Comment: Error details: I have now added them to the question. Using Sushi because the "Phone" model is filled from external API. Want to keep that model separate from my regular models. My use case is similar to https://filamentphp.com/blog/how-to-consume-an-external-api-with-filament-tables

Comment: How does your regular `user` model look like?

Comment: Regular `User` model is default migration. So `id` etc, but no `phone_id` (same as for sushi `User` model).

Comment: and your database contains the `users` table?

Comment: Yes, both of these work: `App\Models\User::first()` and `App\Models\Sushi\User::first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work in the current version of Sushi. I submitted a PR for that, but it was never merged:
https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi/pull/98/

> The reason behind this is that Laravel assumes the related model is in the same database as the one in which the relation is defined unless you explicitly set the connection name on the related model.

Code causing this behavior is in Laravel core: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/be2ddb5c31b0b9ebc2738d9f37a9d4c960aa3199/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L791

As a workaround, you can add this to your `Phone` model:

```
protected function newRelatedInstance($class)
{
    return tap(new $class, function ($instance) use ($class) {
        if (!$instance->getConnectionName()) {
            $instance->setConnection($this->getConnectionResolver()->getDefaultConnection());
            parent::newRelatedInstance($class);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. In that case I guess the statement on the Sushi page comes with caveats: "You can add a relationship to another standard model, just like you normally would". Thanks for the workaround!